# ASP.NET MVC Передаю результат LINQ запроса во View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc, linq

В контроллере создаю linq запрос и передаю его во view
View видит i но не видит i.Flat

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var info = (from f in db.Flats
                   join d in db.Datas on f.IndicatorId equals d.IndicatorId
                   select new
                   {
                       Flat = f.Address,
                       Indicator = f.IndicatorId,
                       Date = d.Date,
                       Value = d.Value
                   }).ToList();


        ViewBag.Info = info;
        return View();
    }
}
```

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: А что возращается в info посмотрите.

Comment: @AzizUmarov `{ Flat = {"address":{"street":"Сакко и Ванцетти","house":"97","flat":"52"}}, Indicator = 5, Date = 11.08.2020 14:53:43, Value = 1674,25 }{ Flat = {"address":{"street":"Ленина","house":"152","flat":"49"}}, Indicator = 6, Date = 12.08.2020 10:42:45, Value = 100,98 }` список объектов

Comment: интересно, а можно screen. почему нет разделителей в списке между объектами

Comment: @AzizUmarov list объектов

Comment: @AzizUmarov почему внутри объекта Flat = ..., Indicator = ..., Date = ... это нормально?

Comment: Да нормально, мне интересно можете проверить что лежит в i в цикле? Почему он не видит нужного объекта

Comment: есть zoom? Покажите что там у Вас

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111706/discussion-between-aziz-umarov-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете анонимный тип - в этом проблема.

Если лень создавать класс-модель, то можно обойтись применением динамики.
Написал linq-код в синтаксисе методов, т. к. в данном случае это проще.

```
var info = db.Flats
    .Join(db.Datas, f => f.IndicatorId, d => d.IndicatorId,
        (f, d) =>
        {
            dynamic exp = new ExpandoObject();
            exp.Flat = f.Address;
            exp.Indicator = f.IndicatorId;
            exp.Date = d.Date;
            exp.Value = d.Value;
            return exp;
        });

ViewBag.Info = info;
```

---

Но лучше использовать класс-модель.
Типы свойств укажите, какие нужны. В примере они сделаны `object`.

```
public class Info
{
    public object Flat { get; set; }
    public object Indicator { get; set; }
    public object Date { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

А дальше код запроса отличается от вашего лишь наличием типа `Info` в селекте:

```
var info = (from f in db.Flats
            join d in db.Datas on f.IndicatorId equals d.IndicatorId
            select new Info
            {
                Flat = f.Address,
                Indicator = f.IndicatorId,
                Date = d.Date,
                Value = d.Value
            });

ViewBag.Info = info;
```

---

Ещё более правильный способ: не использовать `ViewBag`, а передавать модель во вью.

```
var info = (from f in db.Flats
            join d in db.Datas on f.IndicatorId equals d.IndicatorId
            select new Info
            {
                Flat = f.Address,
                Indicator = f.IndicatorId,
                Date = d.Date,
                Value = d.Value
            });

return View(info); // обратите внимание на параметр
```

В представлении добавляем вверху строку с указанием нашей модели:

```
@model IEnumerable<AspNetCore.Models.Info>
```

Естественно, используйте ваше пространство имён.

Так выглядит код прохода по коллекции:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Flat</td>
        <td>@item.Indicator</td>
        <td>@item.Date</td>
        <td>@item.Value</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: как в способе через view добавить условие для фильтрации списка, например для into с одинаковыми indicator выводить то у которого больше date?

Comment: @ИВановИван - не спрашивайте в комментариях. Создайте новую тему.

Comment: Анонимные типы это  не проблема, а часть языка. И появились они не на пустом месте. Надо запомнить тебя Ваня. Чтоб не отвечать на твои вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064302/converting-dynamic-type-to-dictionary-c-sharp) в ответе

```
var myobj = RouteValueDictionary(i);
```

и доступ к свойствам `myobj["Flat"]`

преобразование в массив свойств динамического объекта

Comment: @ИВановИван мне на таких как ты нет смысла терять время.

Comment: @ИВановИван моё время ещё дороже чем у Саши.